# Configure AsciiDoctor Maven plugin to generate a single PDF file

Tags: java, maven, asciidoctor

Is there a way to configure AsciiDoctor Maven plugin to generate one PDF file out of many `.adoc` files?

Currently, it simply translates the structure of asciidoc files into the same structure, but using PDFs. I would like to have a single file and when I click on the link it moves me to the target location in the same PDF. Is this even possible using Maven plugin?

My current pom.xml:

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
    <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctorj-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>documentation</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>target/pdf-doc</outputDirectory>
        <backend>pdf</backend>
        <preserveDirectories>true</preserveDirectories>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-pdf-doc</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <backend>pdf</backend>
                <attributes>
                    <source-highlighter>rouge</source-highlighter>
                    <icons>font</icons>
                    <pagenums/>
                    <toc/>
                    <idprefix/>
                    <idseparator>-</idseparator>
                </attributes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

Comment: Yes this is possible...https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-it-extension/tree/master/itf-documentation (https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-it-extension/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate individual articles into single one like:

```
:toc: macro
:toclevels: 3
:toc-title: Contents
:doctype: book
:chapter-label:

toc::[]

:doctype: book

include::article1.adoc[]

include::article2.adoc[]

...
```

and setup maven plugin to compile that single adoc:

```xml
<configuration>
   <sourceDocumentName>single.adoc</sourceDocumentName>
</configuration>
```

---

It seems the Q is more about `asciidoc` rather than `maven`...

I believe to support document links we need to create anchors with unique names, something like:

building-tool.adoc:

```
[#building_tool]
= Building tool

== Status
Accepted
```

cloud.adoc:

```
[#cloud]
= Cloud

== Status
Accepted
```

adr-log.adoc:

```
| 08/07/2022
| xref:adr/building-tool.adoc#building_tool[Building tool]
| Accepted

| 08/07/2022
| xref:adr/cloud.adoc#cloud[Cloud]
| Accepted
```

Comment: How can I include other files if the parent file has a table with links to other files? Something like this:

`.Table Architecture Decision Record log
[%header, cols = 3]
|===
| Creation date
| Name
| Status

| 08/07/2022
| xref:adr/building-tool.adoc[Building tool]
| Accepted

| 08/07/2022
| xref:adr/cloud.adoc[Cloud]
| Accepted
|===`

Comment: what is the problem? asciidoctor perfectly manages such cases and turns cross-document links into document links.

Comment: Okay, but how do I make that when I click on the link I will be taken somewhere in the same pdf where the content of the .adoc file is?

Comment: do you have a reproducible example where something does not work as expected?

Comment: I have this demo project https://github.com/Serek16/asciidoc. Links doesn't work in the generated file

Comment: @Soutparl you need to create anchors - check the update.

Comment: It works, thanks. It's a pity you have to make that extra file to make it work though